# Hi, I am trying to create a Calculation page: when I run the code, it hides the "Steps" the checkboxes and I'm not sure of the mistakes. Thanks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help complete this Javascript code that satisfies the following requirements:

Create a radio button with the name "Salary Change with Various Steps" and two options: Yes and No.
If the user selects "Yes" for "Salary Change with Various Steps", display two checkboxes named "Second step" and "Third step".
Case 1: If the user selects only the "Second step" checkbox, display a radio button named "Increase based on performance?" with two options: Yes and No. If the user selects "Yes" for "Increase based on performance?", display two text fields named "Field1" and "Field2". Later, calculate the result using the formula: result = (Field1 + Field1/100).
Case 2: If the user selects both the "Second step" and "Third step" checkboxes, display two text fields named "Field3" and "Field4". Later, calculate the result using the formula: result = (Field3 + Field4) * 2.
Case 3: If the user selects only the "Second step" checkbox and "Increase based on performance?" is selected "No", display two text fields named "Field5" and "Field6". Later, calculate the result using the formula: result = Field5 * Field6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Salary Change Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Salary Change Calculator</h1>
  <form>
    <label>
      Salary Change with Various Steps
      <input type="radio" name="salary-change" value="yes" id="radio-yes" onclick="toggleSteps()">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="salary-change" value="no" id="radio-no" onclick="toggleSteps()">No
    </label>
    <div id="steps" style="display:none">
      <h2>Steps</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-second-step">
      <label for="checkbox-second-step">Second step</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-third-step">
      <label for="checkbox-third-step">Third step</label>
    </div>
    <div id="increase-performance" style="display:none">
      <h2>Increase Based on Performance?</h2>
      <input type="radio" name="increase-performance" value="yes" id="radio-performance-yes">
      <label for="radio-performance-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="increase-performance" value="no" id="radio-performance-no">
      <label for="radio-performance-no">No</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Fields</h2>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field1" id="field-1">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field2" id="field-2">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field3" id="field-3">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field4" id="field-4">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field5" id="field-5">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Field6" id="field-6">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
   
 // Get all elements
const radioSalaryChange = document.getElementById("radio-yes");
const stepsDiv = document.getElementById("steps");
const checkboxSecondStep = document.getElementById("checkbox-second-step");
const checkboxThirdStep = document.getElementById("checkbox-third-step");
const increasePerformanceDiv = document.getElementById("increase-performance");
const radioIncreasePerformance = document.getElementById("radio-performance-yes");

const field1 = document.getElementById("field-1");
    const field2 = document.getElementById("field-2");
    const field3 = document.getElementById("field-3");
    const field4 = document.getElementById("field-4");
    const field5 = document.getElementById("field-5");
    const field6 = document.getElementById("field-6");

const calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate-button");
const result = document.getElementById("result");


function toggleSteps() {
    
    if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && checkbox-third-step.checked) {
    // Case 2: Calculate using Field3 and Field4
    document.getElementById("field1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field5").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field6").style.display = "block";
        
        
      } else if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && radioIncreasePerformance.checked) {
        // Case 1: Calculate using Field1 and Field2
            document.getElementById("field3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field5").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field6").style.display = "block";
      } else if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && !radioIncreasePerformance.checked) {
          increasePerformanceDiv.style.display = displaySteps ? "none" : "block";
// Case 3: Calculate using Field5 and Field6
c   document.getElementById("field1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("field4").style.display = "block";
    } else {
// No checkboxes are selected
result.textContent = "No calculation needed";
}
}

// Function to calculate the new salary
function calculateSalary() {
  // Check which case applies
  if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && checkboxThirdStep.checked) {
    // Case 2: Calculate using Field3 and Field4
    const resultValue = (parseFloat(field3.value) + parseFloat(field4.value)) * 2;
    result.textContent = "Result: " + resultValue;
    
    
  } else if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && radioIncreasePerformance.checked) {
    // Case 1: Calculate using Field1 and Field2
    const resultValue = (parseFloat(field1.value) + parseFloat(field1.value)/100) * parseFloat(field2.value);
    result.textContent = "Result: " + resultValue;
   
    
  } else if (checkboxSecondStep.checked && !radioIncreasePerformance.checked) {
    // Case 3: Calculate using Field5 and Field6
    const resultValue = parseFloat(field5.value) * parseFloat(field6.value);
    result.textContent = "Result: " + resultValue;
    
    
  } else {
    // No checkboxes are selected
    result.textContent = "No calculation needed";
  }


  // result.textContent = `New salary: ${salary}`;
}

// Add event listener to calculate button
calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculateSalary);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this script. I will try to list out as many as I can.

1. There is an additional "c" below case 3.
2. radioSalaryChange is not used to change the appearance of the Steps and Fields.
3. toggleSteps uses a variable called "checkbox-third-step.checked" which should be checkboxThirdStep instead.
4. document.getElementById("field1") does not exist. Use document.getElementById("field-1") or field1 declared earlier.

Below I write a sample code that you can take a look and try to implement your solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Salary Change Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="salaryChange" value="yes"> Yes
        </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="salaryChange" value="no" checked> No
        </label>
    </p>
    <div id="steps">
      <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="step2"> Second step
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="step3"> Third step
          </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="performance">
      <p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="performance" value="yes"> Yes
          </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="performance" value="no" checked> No
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Field1: <input type="text" name="field1">
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Field2: <input type="text" name="field2">
          </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="fields">
      <p>
        <label>
            Field3: <input type="text" name="field3">
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Field4: <input type="text" name="field4">
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Field5: <input type="text" name="field5">
          </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Field6: <input type="text" name="field6">
          </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
    </p>
    <p>
      Result: <span id="result"></span>
    </p>
  </form>

  <script>
    function calculate() {
      var salaryChange = document.querySelector('input[name="salaryChange"]:checked').value;
      var step2 = document.querySelector('input[name="step2"]:checked');
      var step3 = document.querySelector('input[name="step3"]:checked');
      var performance = document.querySelector('input[name="performance"]:checked');
      var field1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field1"]').value);
      var field2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field2"]').value);
      var field3 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field3"]').value);
      var field4 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field4"]').value);
      var field5 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field5"]').value);
      var field6 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="field6"]').value);

      var result;
      if (salaryChange === "yes") {
        if (step2 && !step3) {
          if (performance === "yes") {
            result = (field1 + field1 / 100);
          } else {
            result = field5 * field6;
          }
        } else if (step2 && step3) {
          result = (field3 + field(field4)) * 2;
        } else {
          result = "Please select at least the Second step checkbox.";
        }
      } else {
        result = "No salary change selected.";
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
    }

    // Hide/show fields based on user selection
    document.querySelector('input[name="salaryChange"]').addEventListener("change", function() {
      var steps = document.getElementById("steps");
      var performance = document.getElementById("performance");
      var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
      if (this.value === "yes") {
        steps.style.display = "block";
        performance.style.display = "none";
        fields.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        steps.style.display = "none";
        performance.style.display = "none";
        fields.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    document.querySelector('input[name="step2"]').addEventListener("change", function() {
      var performance = document.getElementById("performance");
      var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
      if (this.checked) {
        performance.style.display = "block";
        fields.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        performance.style.display = "none";
        fields.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    document.querySelector('input[name="step3"]').addEventListener("change", function() {
      var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
      if (this.checked) {
        fields.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        fields.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```